# pydev ignores import errors

Tags: eclipse, pydev, code-analysis, importerror

I am refactoring a script using pydev. Because I need to replace some obsolete modules (imported with `from module import *`), I commented out the imports, expecting errors would occur. None has (PyDev 2.7.2+). In PyDev 2.7.1, some errors occurred.

The <kbd>Preferences</kbd>/<kbd>PyDev</kbd>/<kbd>Editor</kbd>/<kbd>Code Analysis</kbd> related settings:

Options:

__Do code analysis?

___checked

__When do we analyze?

___On any successful parse

Undefined:

__Undefined variable:

___Error

__Undefined variable from import:

___Error

Imports:

__Import redefinition:

___Warning

__Import not found:

___Error

---

Would you know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, it'd be nice to update to the latest version (ideally the nightly, which at this point should probably be the next released version).

As for things to check:

1. Are your files under a source folder? (i.e.: is one of the parent folders in the project properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH)
2. Do you have some error in your error log?
3. Do all the parent folders have `__init__.py` (i.e.: if some of the parent folders doesn't have it, the file is not considered to be in the PYTHONPATH and thus is not analyzed).
4. If it's not one of those, it'd be nice if you can add a screenshot of the pydev package explorer showing the project with the file where you have this issue.